# Running a Spring Boot app using NetBeans

Tags: java, spring, maven, netbeans

Well, the thing is that I need to debug a maven based Spring Boot app, so I decided to run it through NetBeans in debug mode, but as soon as I type the project's URL in the browser's search bar it spews the following:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://www.unidatanet.com.br/tag/udtweb-core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:277)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:75)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:243)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:124)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:411)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:469)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1430)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
  at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108)
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:64)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:65)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

So, AFAIK this roughly means NetBeans can't find the custom tag library, even though it actually IS inside the project (listed as a maven dependency in the pom file, and confirmed to be inside the project jar's lib folder after packaging).

But, when I run the jar through the command line, it all works fine. Is there something I'm missing in NetBeans's config so I can run the app through it in debug mode?

I'm asking this because if a solution is found through here it might help others, and out of curiosity as well, since I managed to debug the app remotely, but it's kinda slow (the app is kinda slow by itself, and now even more because of the communication overhead between NetBeans and the jvm running the app).

Comment: How are you running the app from netbeans?

Comment: @M.Deinum, right click on the project -> Run, and also through the green play button in the menu.

Comment: It looks like it runs on non embedded tomcat or that netbeans does something weird with it.